# How can you resize all the images in a notebook section?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, replacement, image, boxes

I've pasted a large number of photos and they are too big which makes scrolling hard. Is there a way to automatically have *Mathematica* size them to 10% or something reasonable without have to click on each on individually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put it to the last cell and evaluate, it will resize all images from InputCells to the width of 100px.

You can of course change affected cell set and output parameters.

```
Do[
 With[{nr = NotebookRead[cell]},
  If[! FreeQ[nr, "ImageGraphics"],

   SelectionMove[cell, Cell, All];
   NotebookWrite[ EvaluationNotebook[],
                  nr /.  g : GraphicsBox[__, BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", ___] :> 
                     ToBoxes@ImageResize[ToExpression[g], 100]
    ];

   ]
  ]
 , {cell, Most@Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]}
 ]
```

Comment: Your programmatic solution works great Kuba. Are you sure, there isn't a manual way to resize multiple graphic outputs in a similar fashion as "shift" /"cmd" click in other programs. Quite often I lack this functionality, especially with lists of graphics/plots.

Comment: @MathLind I'm not sure but I'm not aware of any :) But that's what palettes are for, to customize/add features. So you can use it from a palette's button (after changing `EvaluationNotebook[]` and `Cells[]` appropriately. I can add that code later.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an addition to the excellent [answer by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71579/280) that uses `ImageResize` and hence operates on the Notebook in a destructive way with loss of the original image data. Here is a modification of that solution which works non-destructively and simply sets widths for all images in the `"Input"` `Cell`s equal to 100:

```
Do[With[{nr = NotebookRead[cell]}, 
  If[! FreeQ[nr, "ImageGraphics"], SelectionMove[cell, Cell, All];
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    nr /. g : GraphicsBox[__, BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", ___] :> 
      Append[DeleteCases[g, ImageSize -> _], ImageSize -> {100, Automatic}]];]], {cell, 
  Most@Cells["Input"]}]
```