# Should I rasterize plots to keep my notebook file small?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, system-performance, rasterize, size

I often use *Mathematica* notebooks as an informal "lab notebook", plotting recent results in various tabs and such. I've noticed that these files can tend to get really large; for example, my *Windows* file explorer shows one to be 66MB. Additionally, it can often take about 10 seconds to finish saving a file.  It also tends to be a little "laggy" when I scroll around the plots or open/close the tabs (the alt+5 titles that you can collapse) that I use to organize my work.

My first question is:  What's causing such a delay?  I suspect it's either just having many large datasets (~100,000 pairs) in memory, or maybe it is that when I plot them, the data is still "there"; i.e., the plot isn't just a static image or something.

My second question is:  Is there a smarter way I should be doing this?  My main concern is usually just producing the plots so I can analyze my data quickly.  If it would be faster to raster them so they were just a simple image, that wouldn't bother me.

What's the smartest way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: related: [71575](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71575/5478), [6157](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6157/5478), [13978](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13978/5478)

Answer (score 4):

Is rasterization going to make the notebooks smaller?  It depends on the specific graphics.  The documentation tools in Workbench will rasterize only those plots which actually become smaller in raster form.

I have not delved deep into this, but I think a way to make a rough estimate of the size is this:

```
StringLength@Compress@ToBoxes[graphics]
StringLength@Compress@ToBoxes@Image[graphics]
```

I noticed that graphics that are large tend to be stored in a compressed form in the notebook, so I tried to emulate the same.

If you try this for `graphics = Graphics[Disk[]]` then the vector form is much smaller, obviously.  If you try it for `graphics = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]` then the raster form is smaller.

But rasterizing has drawbacks too: the image won't scale well anymore, and will look pretty bad on high-resolution ("retina") screens.  This is why I do not like to rasterize (I use a retina Mac).

Regarding laggy scrolling:  rasterizing often helps.  I often rasterize for this reason.  [Try this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144891/12) with 100000 points, and rasterization becomes a must.  I prefer the following function because it produces sharp images on a retina screen:

```
rast = Image[Rasterize[#, "Image", RasterSize -> 2 72], Magnification -> 1/2] &
```

Comment: My general approach is to break up files into smaller linked files, as needed, but (as they say) "your mileage may vary."